# How to divide the current after i transform the delta circuit to the Y circuit in this case?

Tags: current, current-divider

The question wants me to find the \$I\$

Question figure:

[image]

Solution:

\$I=\frac{36}{4+2+3}-\frac{36}{6+2+4}=1\$,however,i don't understand why can it be written like that ,can anyone tell me the reason?

Anyway,i want to use my method to solve it,\$666.7m=\frac{2}{3}\$,so i can know \$R_{th}=[(\frac{2}{3}+4)||(1+3)]+2=\frac{18}{5}\$
[image]

So now according to \$V=IR,\$ I can know the current should be \$10A\$,

[image]

however,i don't know how to divide the current to find the \$I_1\$ ,\$I_2\$ and \$I\$,can anyone tell me how to divide the current in this case?

Comment: Well, I can see that the answer is 1 amp but my method involved no writing down stuff and getting confused. The numbers are really easy of course.

Comment: @Andyaka Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: @shineele It's easy. On the left you have a Thevenin equivalent of 18 V and a Thevenin resistance of 2 Ohms. On the right you have a Thevenin equivalent of 12 V and a Thevenin resistance of 2 Ohms, again. In between, you have your 2 Ohm "bridge" resistor, R1. So you have 18 V, 2 Ohms, 2 Ohms, 2 Ohms, 12 V, as a series circuit. This means 6 V difference via 6 Ohms (series total), for 1 A. That's why Andy could do this in his head, even if he were upside down and standing on his head.

Comment: @shineele By the way, your 10 A figure can't be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Andyaka Can you show me how to do that?

Consider this simple modification: -

[image]

I've created V2 (36 volts) just to make the picture easier.

Then if you temporarily remove R1 at the purple squares, you have two voltage sources and two potential dividers: -

- V1 feeding R2 and R4 = 18 volts in series with 2 ohm (R2||R4)
- V2 feeding R3 and R5 = 12 volts in series with 2 ohms (R3||R5)

Now, if you restore R1 you get: -

The net voltage from left to right is 6 volts feeding 2 ohm + 2 ohm (R1) and 2 ohm. This drives 1 amp through R1.

---

### Additional information

> why does 18 volts in series with 2 ohm ,not 36 volts?Why are the R2
>   and R4 parallel,not series?

Think about this: Take V1, R2 and R4 in isolation and ask your self what open circuit voltage they produce and what short circuit current they produce: -

- O/C voltage = 18 volts (because R2 = R4)
- S/C current = 9 amps (because 36 volts / R2 = 9 amps)

So why not use an 18 volt supply in series with a 2 ohm resistor? It will produce: -

- O/C voltage = 18 volts
- S/C current = 9 amps (because 18 volts / 2 ohms = 9 amps)

Now, if you did the math with variables of R2 and R4 you'd find that the equivalent series resistor is R2||R4

Comment: Why are the R2 and R4 parallel,not series?

Comment: why does 18 volts in series with 2 ohm ,not 36 volts?

Comment: It's called source transformation I believe and is part of Norton and Thevenin theorem.

Comment: @shineele why have you unaccepted my answer? Do you require further clarification?

Comment: YES!I need more detail about my question answer and i can accept your answer

Comment: Can you be clearer? You asked me to post the reasoning around the comment I left under your question and that I have done. If there's something you don't understand about my answer I can take you through it but, you must be clear about what you don't understand..

Comment: why does 18 volts in series with 2 ohm ,not 36 volts?Why are the R2 and R4 parallel,not series?

Comment: Does my addition help?

Comment: See also this site that explains and has a calculator: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/thevenin.html